# JavaScript alert

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my homework...
I don't know what's wrong with my code..
my homework is create a simple learning mathematic with level selection...
I use drop down menu for choosing level and arithmetic operations...
now my problem is when I click button then it will go to function start() then save the level and operation that been chosen into 2 variable which are levelselect and operationselect...and now I test it for alert(levelselect); ...supposed it will show the alert window with what level I select...but it can't work... 
thanks to view my post and willing to help me...thanks... ><

```js
<script language="javascript">
var levelselect;
var operationselect;
var num1;
var num2;


function start()
{
                levelselect = form.element["form1"]["level"].value;
                operationselect = form.element["form1"]["operation"].value;
 
alert(levelselect);   
 
} 

</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>


<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table align="center">
<tr align="center"><td><label>Choose your Level :</label>
<select id="level" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center"><br><br><br><td><label>Choose your arithmetic operations :</label>
<select id="operation" >
<option value="add">Addition</option>
<option value="sub">Subtraction</option>
<option value="div">Division</option>
<option value="mul">Multiplication</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
 
<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="button" onclick="start()" value="Generate question"/></td>
</tr>
 

 
</table>
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look in your browser's JavaScript console. Look at the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the form as a javascript variable, you should change the input type and remove the function invocation:

```
<input type="submit"  value="Generate question" />
```

then change:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="start(this);return false;">
```

In this way the function will be invoked on the click of the input but, we are passing this so:

```
function start(myForm) {
    levelselect = myForm["level"]value;
    operationselect = myForm["operation"]value;

    alert(levelselect);

}
```

in the function "start" we have a variable: myForm that can be used to select the two select values

http://jsfiddle.net/L64d5nLe/1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove Script tag from your demo and get Element using ID that solve your problem

```js
var levelselect;
var operationselect;
var num1;
var num2;

function start()
{
    levelselect = document.getElementById("level").value;
    operationselect = document.getElementById("operation").value;
    alert(levelselect);   
    alert(operationselect)
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>


<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table align="center">
<tr align="center"><td><label>Choose your Level :</label>
<select id="level" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center"><br><br><br><td><label>Choose your arithmetic operations :</label>
<select id="operation" >
<option value="add">Addition</option>
<option value="sub">Subtraction</option>
<option value="div">Division</option>
<option value="mul">Multiplication</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
 
<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="button" onclick="start()" value="Generate question"/></td>
</tr>
 

 
</table>
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the form elements like this.

```
levelselect = document.forms["form1"]["level"].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this, you can get select value using id like:

```
document.getElementById("operation").value;
```

this will return selected value for you. you no need to check it using form name. 
I also change type = button to button tag.

```js
  var levelselect;
var operationselect;



function start()
{
                levelselect = document.getElementById("level").value;
                operationselect = document.getElementById("operation").value;
 
                alert(levelselect+" ## "+operationselect);   
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>


<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table align="center">
<tr align="center"><td><label>Choose your Level :</label>
<select id="level" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center"><br><br><br><td><label>Choose your arithmetic operations :</label>
<select id="operation" >
<option value="add">Addition</option>
<option value="sub">Subtraction</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><button  onclick="start()" >Generate question</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Make These Changes in your start function

```
            levelselect = document.getElementById('level').value;
            operationselect = document.getElementById('operation').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I never seen this form.element anywhere.

You should use document.getElementById(id) to take an element of the page to get the value :

```
function start()
{      
    var a = document.getElementById('level');
    var strLevel = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;

    var b = document.getElementById('level');
    var strOperation = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;

    alert(strLevel);   
}
```

Basically you're :

- Selecting the "select" with the help of its "id"
- You're looking into the options for the selected one
- You get the value of the selected one

I've made a jsfiddle for you with this script :

http://jsfiddle.net/0x4ex8tk/6/